# Should I delete an answer if not upvoted or accepted?

Tags: discussion

There are a few times when I really try hard to answer something but then it was kind of abandoned or unnoticed by the OP. No comments, discussion, Upvotes or Acceptance of answer. If no one is paying attention to the answer then it seems better to delete it.

Comment: Why would it seem better to delete it if you have faith in it in the first place?

Comment: While answering I feel it might help but then seeing it abandoned feel like deleting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, don't delete.

It may help someone tomorrow, next week, next month or even next year.

I still get the occasional upvote on answers I posted years ago and when I check I see that the post often has a score of 10 or less.

I've also had acceptances of answers years after I thought the OP had abandoned the site let alone the question.

Comment: Another strange effect is getting multiple upvotes on a very old answer that only has a few votes to being with on same day. Have to assume it is coworkers sharing to solve an issue.

Comment: I concur with this statement. I've been downvoted on some of my answers that are actually the only correct one provided. The general people voting will sometimes not take the time to read through the entire question carefully before condemning certain answers, but they are still helpful for future readers seeking for help. Don't let vote count or lack of discussion hinder you from doing your best to help out.

Answer (score 2):

The OP is only one person. Many people view your post.

It would be nice if people over X reputation could accept the answer for the OP after X days.

Comment: Or maybe mods can have that ability to accept an answer after X days. That would be really great.

Comment: @Pacifist mods are not supposed to have any kind of domain knowledge for their job (even though they all do given their experience as users). They shouldn't have to be able to judge whether one answer is better than the rest. But content becoming obsolete is a problem for which the company claims to be actively working on a solution. Not the exact same situation as your question but needs to same solution.

Comment: OP has no obligation to accept an answer. Also it's not unusual they accept something other than the best practices answer. No reason anyone else should be involved in acceptance process. The votes on answers over time are a far better indicator of quality/value

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you stumble on a very popular & old post with a lot of highly upvoted answers, and you notice that you could add a different answer to the ones already posted.

You add it, but most of the time you don't get upvotes at this moment. But since this question is popular, there's a chance that someone visiting notices your answer and votes for it (it goes both ways, you could get a downvote too...).

So be patient and leave your answer be. The question is good, you'll get voted on eventually.

(And don't be despaired about non-acceptance too much. Acceptance is the opinion of *one* person, votes are much more representative of the answer value)

#### Counter-example

Now, a case where you could delete a 0 score answer is when the question has been closed as duplicate and heavily downvoted. Leaving your answer prevents roomba mechanism (automatic deletion) so if it's not upvoted and considering that the duplicate is bad, maybe it's better to delete it so the question can be automatically deleted (in a word: *don't answer bad/obvious duplicate questions*)